# Who are the core developers behind Ripple?

Tags: development, ripple

Who are the core developers behind [the Ripple system](https://ripple.com/)?

Comment: I know alternative cryptocurrencies are allowed on the Bitcoin stackexchange (sigh ...).  But is Ripple considered a cryptocurrency?

Comment: @StephenGornick Well, they are based on rules of cryptography as far as I know and share a few similarities to Bitcoin. Moreover, the response to discussion on whether or not include Ripple in this SE were all in the "yes" category - http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/335/323 .

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/what-is-joel-katz-role-in-ripple

Answer (score 11):

Chris Larsen has been [publicly identified](http://bitcoinmagazine.com/introducing-ripple/) as CEO of OpenCoin, the company behind the new Ripple. The core developers have been [publicly identified](http://www.businessweek.com/articles/2013-04-11/introducing-ripple-a-bitcoin-copycat) as Jed McCaleb, Arthur Britto, Stefan Thomas, and me (David Schwartz).

Comment: David, I asked quite a few questions here on this thread on Ripple forums, mind taking a look? https://ripple.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=34 I'm not sure that bombarding Bitcoin SE with these would have been that right thing to do.

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/what-is-joel-katz-role-in-ripple

Comment: FYI, David Schwartz = Joel Katz

Answer (score 6):

First of all it's important to point out that Ripple (unlike Bitcoin) has been developed by a company, OpenCoin Inc. There is no information about individual developers on ripple.com or opencoin.com. The following information can be found from the [Whois of opencoin.com](http://www.whois.com/whois/opencoin.com):

```
 Registrant:
 OpenCoin Inc
 268 Bush St #2724
 San Francisco, CA 94104
 US
```

That said Ripple is (will be) open source and decentralized, people can write competing clients and the Ripple network could function in the future without OpenCoin Inc.