# What is Joel Katz' role in Ripple?

Tags: ripple

I see quite a few answers from Joel Katz, and a friend of mine referred to him as "a Ripple founder". Is this true? His name is not mentioned [on this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7554/who-are-the-core-developers-behind-ripple).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"JoelKatz" is the bitcointalk.org handle of [David Schwartz](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/85/david-schwartz). He answered the linked question and referred to himself as "myself", and you should see him listed under this name as a Ripple developer in other places.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder which of the two is his real name, if at all.

Comment: @ripper234: I am fairly confident David Schwartz is the real one as it's used more commonly and in more official places. In fact linking to the SE profile changed my answer as I meant him as a person, not just the SE profile.

Comment: Feel free to revert my edit if you want.

Comment: This answer is correct. My real name is "David Schwartz". I have used the nickname "JoelKatz" for a long time, including on the Bitcoin Forum. If you look at my profile on SE, you'll see this: "I am OpenCoin's Chief Cryptographer and one of the architects of the Ripple payment system."